# Form validation with fields having space as value

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, form, validations

This is the field in the admin side form which is ment to be required.

```
<field name="exam_name" 
type="text"
label="Name"
required="true" />
```

In the form if I leave this field empty (null) then it shows a validation error Invalid Field.

But if I leave a space then it submits the page and space stored in the database.

Is there a way to validate the form even a particular field is having space instead of empty?

Answer (score 1):

You could use client side validation. So firstly, add the following to the form view (Choose one depending on your Joomla version)

```
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation'); // Joomla 3.3
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidator');  // Joomla 3.4
```

Then add the `form-validate` class to your form so it looks like this:

```
<form class="form-validate">
```

Then add the required classes to your form field like so:

```
<field name="exam_name" class="required validate-custom"
```

Then apply the same to your form submit button, like so:

```
<input type="submit" class="required validate-custom"
```

And finally, you can use the following jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    document.formvalidator.setHandler('custom', function (value) {
        // Perform your validation for blank spaces
        // You could use a regex or maybe trim the value
        // Whatever method you prefer
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for this.  Sorry I didn't mention in the question correctly.  I am trying this from admin side.  Is this answer still apply for admin side validation?

Comment: Yes, it will still work. Please note I haven't actually tested this as there may be some minor tweaks you'll have to make

Comment: Thanks for explaining the custom handler.  How can I do this with XML form fields?? Meaning I use the joomla renderField to display the field. How can I add the custom validation handler in this case?

Comment: Client side validation never replaces server side validation...

Answer (score 1):

If your model extends JModelAdmin or JModelForm, you can use its validate function to validate client input before saving it to database.

```
class MyComponentModelForm extends JModelAdmin
{

  ....
  ....

  /* Override */
  public function validate($form, $data, $group = null)
  {
     $data = parent::validate($form, $data, $group = null);
     if(!$data || empty($data['myfield']))
     {
       JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage(JText::_('COM_MYCOMPONENT_FIELD_REQUIRED'));
       return false;
     }

    return $data;
  }
}
```

Comment: setError is deprected.